# Onclick of Gridview button item, Text Color of button item should change

Tags: java, android, gridview, adapter, custom-adapter

I am using custom adapter to set Gridview. When I clicked on Button of GridView Item, another item gridview button also changes. I have even added the layout for reference. In the layout, there is two textView and one button. 
Is there any Programmatical Way?

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.appl_detail_grid_layout, null);
            TextView appDSection = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appD_gv_section);
            final TextView appDdocty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appD_gv_doctyp);
            final Button appDView=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.appD_gv_view);`

            AppDetailAttachment o = new AppDetailAttachment();
            o = osList.get(position);

            appDSection.setText(o.getSection());
            appDdocty.setText(o.getDocTy());
            appDView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    v.setBackgroundColor(mcontext.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                      //  appDView.setTextColor(mcontext.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));

                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

**appl_detail_grid_layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/appD_gv_section"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/appD_gv_doctyp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/appD_gv_view"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@drawable/selector"
        android:text="View"
        android:background="@drawable/rectanglebutton"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

My **GridView**

```
 <GridView
                android:id="@+id/appD_gv"
                android:layout_width="326dp"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
                android:verticalSpacing="3dp"
                android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:columnWidth="500dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:scrollbarSize="3dp"
                android:background="@color/indigo"
                android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/check"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"/>
```

**ScreenShot of My Problem:**

[image: ScreenShot of My Problem]

Comment: `v.setBackgroundColor(mcontext.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));` instance of use                     `setBackgroundColor(mcontext.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));`

Comment: Tried But didn't work @GowthamanM

Comment: i want button as per requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting that error because of scrolling inside gridview. It was affecting view of gridview. So i changed gridview to ExpandableHeightGridView and my problem is solved. Thanks to people who invested time in solving My android problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "holder" along with setTag and getTag.

Comment: Can you please give me an example?